# Unexpected result using PDO in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am a newbie to PDO data Objects. Recently i was fetching data from a table. and i encountered an unexpected result. Still trying to figure out but no success by now.

My table: **test**

```
a
__
23
76
786
988
234
12
13
```

my code

```
<?php
try
{
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','',array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE ));
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ') as $row)
{
    print_r($row);
}
$dbc= NULL;
 }
catch( PDOException $e)
{
print "Error !:".  $e->getMessage()."<br>";
die();
}
?>
```

**The result:**

```
Array ( [a] => 23 [0] => 23 ) Array ( [a] => 76 [0] => 76 ) Array ( [a] => 786 [0] => 786 ) Array ( [a] => 988 [0] => 988 ) Array ( [a] => 234 [0] => 234 ) Array ( [a] => 12 [0] => 12 ) Array ( [a] => 13 [0] => 13 )
```

Here i don't understand why i am getting 2 elements in array:

**[a] => 23** it signifies that column a has value 23

But why i am getting `[0] => 23` along with it???

Comment: assosiative array is along with

Comment: you need to set `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` for getting only `associative` array,

Comment: What you really need is **to read the manual page for the very function you are using**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, PDO will grab a numeric AND an associative array when fetching data. To ensure you only get 1 of the 2, you can specify it as the second parameter in your query function by using either `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUMBER`.

Change

```
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ') as $row)
```

into

```
// Fetch associative
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
```

or

```
// Fetch numeric
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ', PDO::FETCH_NUMBER) as $row)
```

**[edit]**
You can also set the default fetch mode after you created your PDO connection by doing the following:

```
// Set default fetch mode to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When doing that, doing

```
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ')
```

will do exactly the same as

```
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Rahul Added an additional way of setting a fetchmode, please refer to my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because PDO is returning both an associative array and an indexed array, which is the standard option called `FETCH_BOTH`.

See this page http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php on how to use `FETCH_ASSOC` or `FETCH_NUM`.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$query = $db->prepare('........);
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch()){
   // rest of code here
}
```

this is a small problem with `PDO`

Comment: This will still give both a numeric and an associative array.

Comment: in my case it is returning associative array or if he is still facing problem he can use  `$query->bindColumn('column_name', $var_name)`

Comment: You probably set the default fetch mode before calling it then. The OP much likely didn't.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch associative array. You can do like this

```
foreach($dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
```

Otherwaise

```
$dbc->query('SELECT * FROM `test` ')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```